# Can I transfer data from iMac 2015 to MacBook Air 2020 using a cable?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt

I have an iMac Retina 5k 27' Late 2015 and a MacBook Air 2020. The issue is that my iMac won't turn on - it hangs during startup, and diagnostics indicate errors in the file system. I want to transfer all the data from it and then try to restore the system or, if that doesn't help, format the hard drive. I want to transfer the data using a cable to the MacBook.

Here's what I've already done: tried using a Xiaomi USB C - USB 2.0 cable (connected USB C to MacBook, USB 2.0 to iMac) in target disk mode (held down T when starting on iMac). This didn't help - after switching to external disk mode on the iMac, nothing appeared on the MacBook; it didn't detect my iMac.

Can I use the Type C - Type C cable that comes with the MacBook to transfer data using a Type C - USB 2.0 adapter (which I insert into the iMac)?

Or perhaps you could suggest another way for me to transfer data using a cable. In any case, I would appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Short answer is you need *Thunderbolt*, not USB-C.  However, the easiest approach would be to just connect over the network and be done with it

Comment: You would need a [Thunderbolt 2 cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m) and a [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter). Anyway, you definitely cannot use the USB Type A jack on the iMac. FYI, this USB Type A jack on the 2015 iMac works both at USB 2.0 (480 Mb/s) and USB 3.0 (5 Gb/s).